# Number of Cell prototypes exceeds tableview height

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios5, xcode4.2, storyboard

I have a tableview that has a large number of fairly tall dynamic cells.  I've tried creating the prototypes for these but I've run out of height room in the view.

I can't seem to extend the height of the table view, (or the view it's in).  I also can't create the tableview outside the viewController, give it a larger height, and just link to it.

Suggestions?  I know I can create the cells programmatically or from a separate nib, but I'd really like to do it via storyboard.

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured this out myself. Try this:

1. Double-click the table almost anywhere except where there's an existing control. You can also double-click on the outer edge of the table.
2. Note that the table view will show a highlighted section that aligns with the cell you've clicked. You've entered some sort of selection mode.
3. Now use the mouse to scroll up or down. The cells will shift up or down as if you were running the app.